# In android is Heap and Internal/External memory are the same?

Tags: android, memory

When we run our application, is it taking space in heap or internal memory, or in android both are same?

And also what is the Cache/Data size that we see in Device Setting menu under Application menu? is it allocated on Heap or Internal/External memory?

Answer (score 0):

Memory is the [RAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) of a device. Every program on almost every platform uses that to store data and instruction code ([Von Neumann architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture)) required to run the program. The CPU is fed with both instructions and data from the RAM. But only while the program is running.

Java programs (and many more) use part of their memory as [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28programming%29) and a part as [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) to store intermediate data.

Once data needs to persist (program restarts & reboots) you'll end up in internal and external storage. Android devices have something similar to hardwired SD-cards as their [internal / external storage](http://beranger.org/2013/06/14/android-storage-what-nobody-bothered-to-tell-you/). "external" is typically no removable SD card but is found in the filesystem in `/sdcard` (or whatever [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) tells you).

> When we run our application, is it taking space in heap or internal memory?

While running you use Memory (and a heap in there). Your app also consumes internal storage space just for being installed. And if you enable install to SD you'll use storage within the external region.

> or in android both are same?

No. Unless internal memory means RAM, then yes, that's roughly the same.

> And also what is the Cache/Data size that we see in Device Setting menu under Application menu?

That is the size of storage your app consumes. Cache is a special part of your apps folder where you can put files that you don't need forever but helps you to speed up things. E.g. caching downloaded images so next time your app starts you don't have to download them again. Some details here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

> is it allocated on Heap or Internal/External memory?

That would be internal storage.